# How to remove both duplicate values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code for remove duplicate record. It shows me unique values and removes the last duplicate record. However, what I want is, if two passports are the same, remove both elements from the array.

Example

```js
var array = [{
    "PassportNo": "abced",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  {
    "PassportNo": "abcederrr",
    "Name": "Johnss",

  },
  {
    "PassportNo": "abced",
    "Name": "John"

  }
];


function removeDuplicates(originalArray, objKey) {
  var trimmedArray = [];
  var values = [];
  var value;

  for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    value = originalArray[i][objKey];

    if (values.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      trimmedArray.push(originalArray[i]);
      values.push(value);
    }
  }
  return trimmedArray;
}

var noDuplicates = removeDuplicates(array, 'PassportNo');
console.log(noDuplicates);
/*
[
  {
    "PassportNo": "abced",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  {
    "PassportNo": "abcederrr",
    "Name": "Johnss"
  }
]
*/
```

I want like this (remove both values):

```js
[{
  "PassportNo": "abcederrr",
  "Name": "Johnss"
}]
```

Comment: `var removedublicate ==` is comparation, just use one '=' for assignation. Can you also edit it with your result please?

Comment: its mistake. sorry....

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's similar but not a duplicate. OP wants to remove all instances of the item if there is a duplicate, not just the duplicate instance.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  its not duplicate because everyone shows unique value but i want delete total value if its duplicate

Comment: That was not at all clear from the text. You may want to edit the text to make that more clear.

Comment: check example if you have any confusion

Comment: my english not good

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it easier to understand. I removed the AngularJS stuff, because it doesn't really matter to the array question, and it's easier to reproduce without having to build out a controller :).

Comment: if the answer in angularjs its really helpful for me and others because many people use keyword of angularjs

Comment: But the answer will be of use to people who don't use AngularJS. If someone explicitly hides AngularJS-tagged questions (they may not be interested), they will miss this question and its helpful answer. Something to consider, anyway, I'll not edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) after storing counts in a separate object (i.e. only choose passports that have count 1).

```js
var array = [{
    "PassportNo": "abced",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  {
    "PassportNo": "abcederrr",
    "Name": "Johnss",
  },
  {
    "PassportNo": "abced",
    "Name": "John"
  }
];

var passportCounts = array.reduce((map, curr) => {
  if (curr.PassportNo in map) map[curr.PassportNo] += 1;
  else map[curr.PassportNo] = 1;
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(array.filter(p => passportCounts[p.PassportNo] === 1));
```